# What is the TrueType font of java's logical font Monospaced on Windows XP

Tags: java, ubuntu, fonts, intellij-idea, truetype

I've been trying to find what is the TrueType font behind Java's logical Monospaced font
on a Windows XP system.

The reason is that I use this font as my code editor's default font in IntelliJ Idea 10
on Windows XP and I recently moved to an Ubuntu system and want the same font in 
Intellij Idea.
Currently on Ubuntu I get Courier New as the TrueType of Monospaced, and it is clearly 
not the same font as the one used on Windows XP.

Could you please help ?
Thank you.

To be clear, I'm trying to have the Monospaced 12pt WinXP look the same on Ubuntu.
As you can see, the Monospaced 12pt WinXP isn't like any of the other versions.

Follow link for image of the different font appearance:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check `fontconfig.properties.src` under `jre\lib` directory:

```
monospaced.plain.alphabetic=Courier New
monospaced.plain.chinese-ms950=MingLiU
monospaced.plain.chinese-ms950-extb=MingLiU-ExtB
monospaced.plain.hebrew=David
monospaced.plain.japanese=MS Gothic
monospaced.plain.korean=GulimChe

monospaced.bold.alphabetic=Courier New Bold
monospaced.bold.chinese-ms950=PMingLiU
monospaced.bold.chinese-ms950-extb=PMingLiU-ExtB
monospaced.bold.hebrew=David Bold
monospaced.bold.japanese=MS Gothic
monospaced.bold.korean=GulimChe

monospaced.italic.alphabetic=Courier New Italic
monospaced.italic.chinese-ms950=PMingLiU
monospaced.italic.chinese-ms950-extb=PMingLiU-ExtB
monospaced.italic.hebrew=David
monospaced.italic.japanese=MS Gothic
monospaced.italic.korean=GulimChe

monospaced.bolditalic.alphabetic=Courier New Bold Italic
monospaced.bolditalic.chinese-ms950=PMingLiU
monospaced.bolditalic.chinese-ms950-extb=PMingLiU-ExtB
monospaced.bolditalic.hebrew=David Bold
monospaced.bolditalic.japanese=MS Gothic
monospaced.bolditalic.korean=GulimChe
```

Also note that font rendering on Linux differs from Windows a lot, see [IDEA-57233](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57233) for more details.

You can try to copy Windows ttf font files to Linux:

- couri.ttf
- courbi.ttf
- courbd.ttf
- cour.ttf

Install them there instead of the Linux Courier New version (if it's different) and then set this font in IDEA.

According to your screenshot letters on Windows XP look the same in Monospaced and Courier New fonts, so it's the same font. Digits look different, but it's probably some JVM issue.

On Ubuntu Monospaced font is different, it's by design, however Courier New looks the same as on Windows XP except different aliasing/hinting/rendering which is also by JVM design. You can see how to tweak it from the IDEA issue linked above.

Comment: Hi, I checked Courier New already. 
Clearly not the font in use but thanks.

Comment: You may want to attach the screenshot of the monospaced font on Windows XP, Courier New font on Windows XP and Courier New font on Linux in IDEA so that we can see what's the problem.

Comment: Hi, can the problem with the digits between Monospaced and Courier New on WinXP be the result of a JVM issue ? 
If the TrueType of Monospaced (logical) is Courier New shouldn't it be rendered the same (the same font) ? 

To give better background: The main difference which bugs me is the
difference in digits appearance. This all started when I tried to run one of many swing apps I develop on an Ubuntu machine (cause I changed my dev station). What happend was that digits in numeric text fields were much bigger then on WinXP so the fixed field sizes weren't big enough anymore.